# Disable collapse of admin meta boxes

Tags: jquery, admin, metabox

I have been attempting to disable the ability to collapse admin meta boxes. By the looks of it WordPress creates this functionality in postbox.js /wp-admin/js/ but I have been unable to find a hook or suitable JavaScript to overwrite the built in functions.

This is a some test code I am working with:

```
jQuery('.postbox h3, .postbox .handlediv, .hndle').bind('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;

});
```

Any thoughts on how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your functions file and it will kill the metabox toggles:

```
function kill_postbox(){
    global $wp_scripts;
    $footer_scripts = $wp_scripts->in_footer;
    foreach($footer_scripts as $key => $script){
        if('postbox' === $script)
            unset($wp_scripts->in_footer[$key]);
    }
}
add_action('admin_footer', 'kill_postbox', 1);
```

Comment: Thanks Brian. That seems to the trick nicely. Do you know if removing the entire 'postbox' script in this way causes other issues?

Comment: It does affect user column preferences and the sortable metaboxes. You could clone postbox-dev.js and remove the toggle features, place it in your theme js folder and enqueue your hacked version with a dependency on 'jquery-ui-sortable'.  This would preserve those other functions.

Comment: Thanks Brian. Luckily I do not need the sorting either so this is a silver bullet!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work (any more), postbox is removed from the in_footer array, but is loaded nonetheless. Found a working solution [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39723/unbind-postbox-click-handler), which neatly unbinds the click-handler, and leaves all other postbox functionality in place.

Answer (score 1):

For current Wordpress version (4.5.3) I come up with the following solution which removes closing metaboxes handler and opens all previously closed metaboxes.

**php (plugin.php)**

```
function add_admin_scripts( $hook ) {    
  wp_register_script( 'disable_metabox_toggling', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'index.js', 'jquery', '1.0.0', true);
  wp_enqueue_script( 'disable_metabox_toggling' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_admin_scripts', 10, 1 );
```

**js (index.js)**

```
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.postbox .hndle').unbind('click.postboxes');
     $('.postbox .handlediv').remove();
     $('.postbox').removeClass('closed');
  });
})(jQuery);
```

If you want to use it inside theme you should replace `plugin_dir_url(__FILE__)` with `get_template_directory_uri()` or `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` for a child theme.

Comment: This is better than unloading the whole postbox script, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Simplified & best version :

```
function disable_metabox_folding()
{ ?><script>
    jQuery(window).load(function() {
       jQuery('.postbox .hndle').css('pointer-events', 'none');
       jQuery('.postbox .hndle').unbind('click.postboxes');
       jQuery('.postbox .handlediv').remove();
       jQuery('.postbox').removeClass('closed');
    });
    </script><?php
}

add_action('admin_footer', 'disable_metabox_folding');
```

//thanks to @jmarceli for hints

Comment: What about removing/disabling the sort arrow as well?