# Unbind postbox click handler

Tags: jquery, metabox

I'm trying to unbind the click handler on post metaboxes so they no longer hide when the handle is clicked. I need to do this because I use the handle to contain `<select>` elements & when changing these the `click` event is fired.

The code that binds the click handler is here: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/js/postbox.dev.js#L8

Unfortunately the only way to unbind it seems to be editing this file & inserting the unbind inside `add_postbox_toggles`

Hope anyone can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just put the necessary javascript in a file and enqueue it on the necessary page:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_admin_scripts', 10, 1 );
function add_admin_scripts( $hook ) {    
//You can globalise $post here and enqueue the script for only certain post-types.
    if ( $hook == 'post-new.php' || $hook == 'post.php') {
        wp_register_script( 'my_js_handle','/path/to/js/my-js-file.js',array('jquery'),1,true);
        wp_enqueue_script('my_js_handle');
   }
}
```

With the javascript file containing:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       jQuery('.postbox h3, .postbox .handlediv').unbind('click.postboxes');
    });
```

(In, fact you could probably just 'print' it in the admin-footer).

Comment: Wow thank you so much, that worked a treat! But now I'm confused. Im currently calling add_action() inside a class constructor, which caused the problem. If I move it outside of the class however it works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I will share my code and I hope someone reviews it since I'm not expert in event handling.

This goes inside your plugin or your theme functions.php:

```
/**
 * Disable meta box toggling (collapse/expand) for specified post types
 */
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'wpse_39723_disable_metabox_toggle' );
function wpse_39723_disable_metabox_toggle() {    

    $current_screen = get_current_screen();

    // Array of post types where we want to remove metabox toggling
    $post_types = array(
        'post',
        // 'page',
        // 'my_custom_post_type',
    );

    if( in_array( $current_screen->id, $post_types ) ) {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {
                $( '.postbox' ).removeClass( 'closed' );
                $( '.postbox .hndle' ).css( 'cursor', 'default' );
                $( document ).delegate( '.postbox h3, .postbox .handlediv', 'click', function() {
                    $( this )
                        .unbind( 'click.postboxes' )
                        .parent().removeClass( 'closed' );
                } );
            } );
        </script>
        <?php       
    }
}
```