# Disable closing on metaboxes

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

I'm trying to force a metabox open and not let the admin close it for a custom post type, is this possible? See below for the code that creates the box.

```
  function cwf_create_enquiry_metabox_html() // Create custom metabox HTML
  {
    $post_id = $_GET['post'];

    echo '<p class="sender_information">' . wpautop(esc_textarea(get_post_meta($post_id, 'message', true))) . '</p>';
    echo '<p class="sender_information">Received: <b>' . get_the_time('j F Y @ H:i', $post->ID) . '</b></p>';
  }

  function cwf_create_metabox() // Add custom metabox to "form-submission" post type
  {    
    add_meta_box('sender-information', 'Sender Information', 'cwf_create_sender_information_metabox_html', 'form-enquiry', 'side');
  }
  add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'cwf_create_metabox');
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Found this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31941/disable-collapse-of-admin-meta-boxes but it did not work for me on WP 4.6.1.

Comment: Sadly in WP 4.7 I had the same result. Nice idea though to loop through all the scripts and unset the one that's causing the toggle. Might look into trying to get that idea to work myself.